# Select All options and Disable not working in IE

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

I'm having an issue in IE8 multiselect
we are using jQuery to selectall and disable the list. List is  being disabled but not selected and the same scenario is working perfectly in FireFox where the entire list is selected and disable

Can anyone help me how to handle this issue in IE

Thanks in advance

Below is my code:

```
<select name="weekdays" id="weekdays" disabled="disabled" multiple>
  <option value="Monday">Monday </option>
  <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
  <option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
  <option value="Thursday">Thursday </option>
  <option value="Friday">Friday</option>
  <option value="Saturday">Saturday</option>
  <option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

**ways :**

```
$('select:disabled');
```

or :

```
$('select[disabled=true]'); // [disabled*=true]
```

or :

```
$('select').find('*[disabled=true]');
```

Answer (score 0):

Well here's how I'd do it:

```
$("#weekdays option").prop("selected",true);
```

Given the html you show already has `disabled="disabled"` I don't see why you need jQuery to disable it, but to both disable the select and select all the options:

```
$("#weekdays").prop("disabled",true).find("option").prop("selected",true);
```

This works in IE7; I don't have IE8 to test with.

UPDATE: It occurs to me that maybe the problem you're having is that the selected values aren't submitted. [Disabled form elements don't get submitted.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.12) A common workaround for this is to create hidden inputs to hold the required values. However, I'd be surprised if FF doesn't follow this rule.

Comment: I want it to be disabled and the options should be selected, my problems the options are disabled but now showing as selected

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying you want the options to _be_ selected but not _look_ selected? Or in that comment was "now" a typo that should've said "not"? You said in the question that your code works in Firefox, but when I tried my code it looked (near enough to) the same in Firefox and IE.

Comment: Yes I want the options to be selected and disabled. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what else to suggest. As I mentioned already, the code I showed behaves pretty much the same in IE7 and FF, but I don't have IE8 to test with.